# Angular & Spring MVC - Issue With Post Method - 415 Unsupported Media

Tags: angular, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have the following Spring API:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowCredentials = "true", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping(value = "/seanPost", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Content-Type=application/json")
public  JSONObject post(@RequestBody TrackFileStatusFindForm form, HttpServletRequest request ) {
```

When I use postman to test it it works fine.

In my test Angular app I usually get the error Error 415--Unsupported Media Type. I noticed that angular is setting Content-Type as text/plain whereas Postman sets Content-Type: application/json

I tried setting the header in Angular as seen below but then I get a CORS issue blocking the request and an error of 401 unauthorized in the dev tools.

```
options = {
headers: new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    
  };

onSubmit() { 

this.http.post(this.APP_URL + '/s/seanPost/', JSON.stringify(this.model), this.options)
.subscribe(
    data => {
        this.postId = data;
        console.log(this.postId);
    },
    error => {
    console.log('Error occured', error);
  }
)
```

}

I have tried adding a CORS filter to SpringMVCConfig

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            .allowedHeaders("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Accept", "X-Requested-With", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin")
        .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin");

}
```

But it doesn't seem to help.

The REST URL is https if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to make the request with fetch instead of http.post?

Comment: @tufonas no I will try it now

Comment: does it work when you allow all origins? ie. "*"

Comment: @IanPreglo no it only works if I specify the URL

Comment: @tufonas got the same error with fetch

Comment: I just noticed that...you use `this.APP_URL + '/s/seanPost/'` as url but your endpoint is `/seanPost`.That `/s`?

Comment: @tufonas the /s is added by Spring and a similar get is working fine and via postman is fine